Does a Pokemon's type affect the stardust/candy power up cost in Pokemon Go?
Does the type of the Pokemon (e.g. Grass) affect how much stardust and candy you use to power up the Pokemon? Or is it determined some other way?

No, a Pokemon's type does not factor in to the power-up cost.
How powering up works
When a Pokémon is powered up, its level increases by 1/2, up to a maximum of the trainer's level+10.
Every 2 levels (i.e. 4 power ups), the amount of Stardust needed to power up again increases. Every 10 levels (20 power ups), the candy cost of powering up increases by 1.
Note that a Pokemon's level is a hidden stat, not directly visible. You can gauge how far along a Pokemon is by looking at the Stardust/Candy cost, as well as the white semicircle on the Pokemon summary screen. The more of the semicircle that is filled in, the higher the level of the Pokemon.
Also note that Pokemon above level 40 require XL candies to power up further.
Other modifiers to power up cost
If a Pokemon is Lucky, Purified, or Shadow, certain modifiers are applied to the power up cost:

Lucky Pokemon have 50% less stardust cost
Purified Pokemon have 10% less cost of Stardust and Candy
Lucky, Purified Pokemon get both of these benefits, resulting in an overall 55% decrease in Stardust cost
Shadow Pokemon have their Stardust cost increased by 20%

Check out the Power up table on the Pokemon Go Wiki

No, Pokemon type does not affect power up costs.

While not "type" per se, you could include that a pokemon being lucky, shadow, and purified do affect stardust and candy
